# How can I solve this SQL QUERY by Recursion in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

There is an Employee id and a Manager ID with LAST_NAME in table. I want to show all the superiors of the employees whose last name is Urman. How can I solve this? I know this can be done with recursion. But I am unable to solve this. What would be the easiest query?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+and+([hierarchical-data]+or+[recursive-query])

Comment: You can solve this with a recursive query, but that is not the only way. This can also be done using a ```CONNECT BY```. This is a good place to start: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_GQMLEEPG5ARVSIFGQRD3SES92.html

Comment: @Abra there is "URMAN" in database and however I showed some of the samples in the picture and so you can't see that. But the table has a row whose last_name is Urman.